# Deploying spring project in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I created a sample Maven MVC project using my Spring tool suite but unable to deploy to tomcat.

The problem is when I right click the project and click "Run as" I don't see the "Run on server" option..

I tried changing the project to Dynamic web module after selecting the properties-project facets

but get the error, "Dyanmic web module 3.0 requires Java 1.6 or more"

How do I enable my project to run in Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your Maven project compile for Java 1.6. Add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Should I convert the dynamic web project if so, why do we need to convert it. What is the purpose of spring tools suite as we convert it.

Comment: Well, since the dynamic web module 3.0 requires Java 1.6, and maven does not by default compile for 1.6, you have to instruct maven to do so. So yes, you have to convert the project (`pom.xml`) a bit. Guess they missed that in the tools suite?